# Why isn't "connoisseur" spelled "connaisseur"?

Tags: history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, loanwords, french

From what I gathered on the Web, "connoisseur" is spelled that way because it is derived from the Old French verb "connoître" (to know) which has been spelled "connaître" for close to two centuries. Thus, the spelling I would expect as a native French speaker would be "connaisseur". Is there a historical reason why in the last two centuries the correction in French has not been accepted by the English speaking community?

*Bonus question:* "connaisseur" would most probably be understood in the context of a conversation with a native speaker but I have personally never heard or read anyone using it and it sounds odd. Why would it be used in English in the first place? Is it for the same kind of false sense of culture it gives to the speaker that drives English speaking people to include French words in their conversations?

Comment: In my experience "*connoisseur*" is used by native speakers with reasonable frequency, and does not sound pretentious or forced. It's just a word that fits in certain circumstances, like "*hors d'oeuvres*", and unlike, for example, "*forte*", "*je ne sais quoi*", or "*savoir faire*", which all sound self-conscious and pretentious to my ear (and are much less common than "connoisseur").

Comment: As to spelling, once English borrows a word from a foreign language, the connection to that word in its original language is broken. It doesn't track "updates", it operates independently. English dictionaries record "connoisseur" as "connoisseur", and so, in English, that's how it's spelled.

Comment: See also: "*aficionado*".

Comment: @DanBron I should say that *forte* is very common where I live, not considered pretentious at all.

Comment: @Dan You consider _connoisseur_ and _hors d’oeuvre(s)_ to be more common than _forte_? I think I would probably say that such-and-such is not my forte quite a lot more commonly than I would find the need to be discussing hors d’oeuvres, by and large.

Comment: @Anonym, really?  Where do you live?  And how to people pronounce it? Like in "fortress", or "four-tay"?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, round these parts (NYC), no one really says "my forte", and when they do, eyes tend to roll.  I wouldn't say "*hors d'oeuvres*" is *common*, per se, but it's a normal way to refer to pre-meal snacks, and in that context is used without irony or pretension (at this point, it doesn't even sound particularly *French*, if that makes sense).

Comment: @DanBron The west coast of Canada.  It is usually pronounced like the latter, but the former is not non-existent.

Comment: I would not call a change in spelling a "correction".

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it for the same kind of false sense of culture it gives to the speaker that drives English speaking people to include french words in their conversations ?" What about the English loan-words in French, like parking, weekend, smoking, tennis, jeans, and pullover?

Comment: All those loan-words that you mentioned are used daily by almost everybody here in Quebec. This does not seem to be the case with the examples of french words used in english in the comments with the exception of "hors d'oeuvres" which really describes an entrée (see what I did there ?). It does seem, to me, that quite often there is some sort of pretentiousness that usually comes with the use of french words in english but that could be my own subjective interpretation.

Comment: While _amateur_ is more common for that meaning and has some other meanings, _connaisseur_ [is used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connaisseur%2Camateur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3) in French (it could be a transatlantic difference, that could be a subject for f.se).

Comment: Cobaltduck, the full stop should be after an inverted comma after 'connaisseur'. It was correct before. http://www.economist.com/style-guide/inverted-commas-quotation-marks

Comment: @DanBron, I realise that a lot of time has passed and you might not remember what you were thinking, but why '*See also: "aficionado"*'? That still shares its spelling with Spanish. Or is it a follow-on to your first comment and not your second comment?

Comment: @PeterTaylor If I had to reverse engineer from my comments reading them today... it’s another word like “connoisseur”. It’s English now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Why spell it *connoisseur*?

You’ve basically answered your own question here.

The French word has been spelt *connaître* **for close to two centuries**.

*Connoisseur* was borrowed into the English language some time around **three centuries** ago, when it was spelt that way in French.

The fact that French has changed the spelling of the *French* since does not mean that English (who is, generally speaking, very conservative about changing spellings) will change the spelling of the *English* word.

Similarly, around the same time as *connoisseur* was borrowed, the verb itself was also borrowed as *reconnoitre* (now spelt *reconnoiter* in American English—one of the places where English has changed spellings, though in a more or less systematic fashion). That word is pronounced with the stress on the ‹oi›, which is pronounced as /oi/. ‘Updating’ the spelling to the current French spelling would make the spelling *less* representative of the pronunciation of the word, which would be silly. When English spelling does get updated, at least it’s usually to make it *more* representative of pronunciation.

French has undergone a sound change, whereby the older diphthong /oi/ split into two different forms: one was /wa/, the other /ai/, which was later monophthongised into /ɛ/. The first of these is still spelt ‹oi› (as in *François*), whereas the latter is now spelt ‹ai› (as in *Français*). But this change mainly happened at a stage where many words had already entered the English language, and thus it was not reflected in those English words.

Some words were borrowed later on, though, and in those words, the English pronunciation/spelling match that of Modern French: in *je ne sais quoi*, the last word is pronounced /kwa/ as in Modern French; and in *reconnaissance* (which was borrowed about a century later than *reconnoitre* and *connoisseur*), the spelling in French had already changed, so the English form matches the Modern French form.

#### Why use the word at all?

Your second question seems to be doing the same as your first question: implicitly assuming that French does not change. This is of course not so.

If you look in a French dictionary, the word *connaisseur* is indeed there. My Hachette *Dictionnaire de la Langue Française*, for example, defines it very simply:

> **connaisseur, euse** *a, n* Expert en une chose.

The fact that this is not a word French people tend to use nowadays doesn’t mean they didn’t 300 years ago when it was borrowed into English. The fact that it was borrowed at all suggests that they did, in fact.

Whether a word stops being used and fades into obscurity or maintains its popularity in any given language is completely unpredictable. The fact that this word has all but vanished from colloquial French, but managed to stay alive and kicking in English, is quite random and could not have been predicted; but once the word was there in English, there’s no reason the English should stop using it just because the French did.

Comment: I also recall various English borrowings from French provoking various reactions from French speakers who say, for example, "but we don't say 'double entendre' in French!"  As I understand it, however, they did say it when the English language borrowed the phrase.  (Or am I thinking of a different phrase?)

Comment: @phoog, I doubt _double entendre_ was ever used in French as it is not really grammatically sound.  It looks to me like a modification of _double entente_ which exists and is a quasi synonym of _ambigu_ (which means ambiguous).

Comment: @ANonNativeSpeaker A brief search on the internet confirms your suspicion about *double entente*.

Comment: Based on the Wikipedia article "[Phonological history of French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French)", the split in the reflexes of "oi" apparently occurred after "ai" had already become a monophthong /ɛ/. My understanding is that the development was something like [oɪ̯] > [o̯e] > [wɛ], [ɛ] > [wa], [ɛ].

Comment: @sumelic Hmm, that’s possible, I suppose. I don’t have access to the primary source the Wikipedia article gives, so I don’t know what their arguments are, but the fact that <oi> in many English loan words from the 15th–17th centuries are pronounced /oɪ/ to me speaks against a change to /we/ by 1300. I’d always been taught a two-way split: (1) [oɪ̯] > [ɜɪ̯] > [aɪ̯] > [ɛ], and (2) [oɪ̯] > [o̯ɪ] > [o̯e] > [o̯ɛ] > [o̯a] > [wa]. Not sure how we can tell which is truer, apart from loan words (which, at first glance at least, fit better with the latter, I think).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Interesting! Maybe I will ask a French SE question on this topic.